# Failed to resolve: android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-alpha1 android studio 3.0

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-studio-3.0, android-architecture-components

I am building a project in android studio 3.0 with android plugin `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha1'` and gradle version `gradle-4.0-milestone-1-all.zip`.

Used maven repo as well:

```
maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
      }
```

Also, Using android Room persistence and lifecycle in my project. Already declared below dependencies in my app gradle file:

```
compile "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-alpha1"
compile "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0-alpha1"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.0.0-alpha1"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-alpha1"
```

When Sync and build the project it's showing below error:

`Failed to resolve: android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-alpha1`

Am I missing something or any other solution for this issue.

Comment: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/issues/2

Comment: did you add `maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }` ?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya yes, updating my question with that also.

Comment: post `build.gradle`

Comment: This error appeared when I was not connected to the Internet. Connecting to the Internet resolved the error.

Answer (score 30):

I have fixed the issue by updating my app `build.gradle` file like below:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha2'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Actually had to remove the maven repository from `buildscript` repositories and added to `allprojects` repositories as shown above. Also you can keep the maven repository at both places but must include in `allprojects` repositories to fix the issue.

Comment: And this is why I hate Gradle.

Answer (score 7):

Add in app/gradle file

```
compile "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-alpha4"
compile "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0-alpha4"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.0.0-alpha4"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-alpha4"
```

add maven to project based gradle

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}
}
```

it will compile easily

Answer (score 3):

am find solution work with me Room
Dependencies for Room, including testing Room migrations and Room RxJava

```
dependencies {
    def room_version = "1.1.1"

    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version" // use kapt for Kotlin

    // optional - RxJava support for Room
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:$room_version"

    // optional - Guava support for Room, including Optional and ListenableFuture
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:guava:$room_version"

    // Test helpers
    testImplementation "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:$room_version"
}
```

as the document says: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components

Answer (score 2):

you can change "https://maven.google.com" to "https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/" to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You require latest  gradle version 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha2' and Studio Version 3.0+ to use Room

Answer (score 1):

Just add `maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }` to your project gradle

Answer (score 0):

open preference for mac or you can open setting for windows then search proxy setting inside the open window then unchecked proxy authentication it will work