# error: package android.arch.lifecycle does not exist

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I am getting error: package android.arch.lifecycle does not exist and i tried to resolve it,
i used below links : but none of these resolve it:

[Failed to resolve: android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-alpha1 android studio 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44280511/failed-to-resolve-android-arch-lifecycleextensions1-0-0-alpha1-android-studio)
[Could not resolve android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52311406/could-not-resolve-android-arch-lifecycleextensions1-1-0/52313242)

i have below dependencies :

```
 // Room components
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$rootProject.roomVersion"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:$rootProject.roomVersion"

    // Lifecycle components
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$rootProject.archLifecycleVersion"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$rootProject.archLifecycleVersion"
```

Recently I got this link:
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#java
which says : The APIs in lifecycle-extensions have been deprecated. Instead, add dependencies for the specific Lifecycle artifacts you need.

Does this mean now I need to use individual packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the answer.
android.support is deprecated , i migrated to androidx via following links:

https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/migrating-to-androidx-tip-tricks-and-guidance-88d5de238876
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

And at last if you get error like buttler knife/ (or any third party lib) not resolved, find android x compatible version
i used:

```
// butter knife
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.0.0'
```

Answer (score 2):

The `android.arch` packages have been deprecated, try using `androidx` packages instead. Also make sure you've added `google()` in your build.gradle.